# Ext2 filesystem for /boot partition

Tags: filesystems, boot, boot-loader, ext2

Is the `ext2` filesystem good for `/boot` partition? I set `ext4` for `/ root` partition, but wasn't sure which filesystem to select for the /boot partition, and I just set **ext2**. Does it matter in this case?

Comment: Yes, ext2 is perfectly suited for boot.

Comment: Why not just use ext4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only matters if you're going to use the ancient GRUB, ext4 is only supported by GRUB2.

ext2 is simple, robust and well-supported, which makes it a good choice for /boot.

Comment: Does ext2 use less space compare with ext4, as ext2 does not maintain a journal?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Does Ext2 still acceptable for `/boot` partition of **SSD disk**, as Ext2 does not support `TRIM`? (and TRIM function is very important for SSD disk for efficient performance).

Comment: Please open a new question

Comment: @triwo Your `/boot` partition (1) should not be that large and (2) not change very often, so not using TRIM is unlikely to have any noticeable detrimental effects.

Comment: It also matters if you are installing Linux on a PowerPC machine (ie: New World Apple Hardware) as yaboot cannot recognize newer ext filesystems as it's built against ext2.

Answer (score 2):

**summary:** ext2 is a bad choice for `/boot`, since (unless I'm missing something or am very unlucky) it appears to prevent "normal" update of GRUB2.

**details:**

Today I was updating a 2010-vintage laptop that

- runs a Debian distro (LMDE2)
- shipped with win7, which I dualbooted with an unmanaged Linux `/boot` partition and a managed (LVM2-on-LUKS) partition:

  ```
  $ sudo fdisk -l
  Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  ...
  Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
  /dev/sda1            2048  34818047  34816000 16.6G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
  /dev/sda2  *     34818048 239618047 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda3       239618048 240642047   1024000  500M 83 Linux
  /dev/sda4       240642048 976773119 736131072  351G  5 Extended
  /dev/sda5       240644096 976773119 736129024  351G 83 Linux


  $ df -h
  Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/dm-2                     20G   12G  7.2G  62% /
  ...
  /dev/sda3                    485M   73M  387M  16% /boot
  /dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-home  322G  292G   31G  91% /home
  ```

I.e., `/dev/sda5` ~= `/dev/dm-2`: it's a LUKS-encrypted partition on which LVM2 manages partitions for root, swap, and home.

```
$ mount | grep -e '^/dev/'
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext2 ...
/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-root on / type ext4 ...
/dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-home on /home type ext4 ...
```

(Note the `/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext2` above.) My experience today doing a package update/upgrade (on a debian box, if that makes a difference):

The package manager wanted to update the kernel, GRUB, and `libc`; to be specific, the packages

```
base-files
grub-common
grub-pc
grub-pc-bin
grub2-common
linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common
linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
linux-kbuild-3.16
linux-libc-dev
```

Package install appeared to be going well until

```
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
```

At about this point, my console went to character-mode-graphics to present a dialog with title=`Configuring grub-pc` and body=

```
GRUB failed to install to the following devices:

/dev/dm-2

Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly.

Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue?
```

I hit button=No, and would now like to know [how to {best, least destructively}](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259728/how-to-resume-grub2-upgrade-apparently-blocked-by-boot-filesystem-type-ext2)

1. update my /boot from ext2
2. update GRUB2