# how to resume GRUB2 upgrade apparently blocked by /boot filesystem type=ext2?

Tags: debian, package-management, grub2, ext2

### details

As detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259712/38638), the `/boot` on this Debian Jessie had filesystem type=ext2

```
$ mount | grep -e '^/dev/'
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext2 ...
...
```

and was unable to upgrade its GRUB2

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
...
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
```

At about this point, my console went to a [curses TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) to present a dialog with title=`Configuring grub-pc` and body telling me that `GRUB failed to install`:

```
Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly.
Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue?
```

I hit button=`No`. At that point,

- the GRUB2 packages={`grub-common`, `grub-pc`, `grub-pc-bin`, `grub2-common`} were installed (per `apt-get` and `aptitude`) but not fully configured (per message above).
- I had the following

### questions

**1.** Should I now should update my {`/dev/sda3`, `/boot`} from filesystem type=ext2 to something else (presumably ext4)?

If I am misunderstanding the situation: what do I need to know? Is there something I should do to debug?

If I am *not* misunderstanding: what's the {easiest, most reliable, least disruptive} way to convert `/boot`'s filesystem, on Debian (which this box is running)? [fstransform](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fstransform)?

**2.** Should I should now reconfigure GRUB2? E.g., how do I (or another Debian user in same situation) recreate the `Setting up` actions (see second text block) induced by the package install?

### answers

**1.** It seemed clear to me that I should update my {`/dev/sda3`, `/boot`} from filesystem type=ext2 to ext4, which I did with [fstransform](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform) (installing its [Jessie package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fstransform) as detailed [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tlroche/eyXRq). This seemed to go well (except for [one problem](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform/issues/5)).

However this filesystem upgrade may not have been necessary, per Jordan Uggla [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-grub/2016-02/msg00019.html).

**2.** Per [Uggla's post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-grub/2016-02/msg00019.html), I reconfigured GRUB2 with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc --frontend=text` as detailed [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tlroche/E8rAx).

I now see and boot to the updated kernel and have no boot-time error messages.

Answer (score 0):

See details in **answers** above: I updated {`/dev/sda3`, `/boot`} from filesystem type=ext2 to ext4, then ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc --frontend=text`. I now see and boot to the updated kernel and have no boot-time error messages.